# using adb to remove an application in bash script

Tags: bash, apk, adb, root

I have put together a bash script that automates the installation and removal of various apks.

The script uses adb to install to sdcard then uninstall packagename to remove. If it has problems finding the package name (it's only happened if the AndroidManifest is broke) it reverts to using adb to get to the applications menu via shell input keyevent "direction" to the sdcard section then as there will only be one app here it selects it and removes it.

The problem is that the script now has to run on a nexus 5 running kitkat.. so the only way to view the app list is by way of 'downloaded apps', 'running apps' and 'all apps'. The install will now be to the handset not sdcard as nexus has no sdcard.

Can anyone recommend a way to find the last installed app to android 4.4 so I can use its name within a variable to remove it? I've been told to try pm list packages, but this is no good as I won't know what the app is called when away from the phone.

The handset is rooted if that helps..

thanks